# Google search history still showing up

Tags: firefox, google-search

Up until very recently, my search history for Google hasn't been cached, and that's just how I like it. But not long ago, it started to keep my history and I don't know how to turn it off. I have unchecked everything I can find in Firefox and my Google account that has anything to do with keeping search history. Also, I can't seem to delete it either, other than one search at a time.

Is there anything I have missed?

[image]

Comment: Did you clear your browser history and cache? You also need to delete your search history on https://myactivity.google.com

Comment: @SpiderPig That deletes the history, but it doesn't prevent new history to show up. I simply don't want my Google search history to show up at all.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Google - it's the Firefox settings. Under **Preferences** (**Options** on Windows) -> **Privacy** -> **History**, you can control what is saved and also what is cleared on exit. Browsing history and form history are linked, so you can't inhibit/clear one without the other.

Comment: @AFH Ok, now I see. But I'm pretty sure I have been able to keep my browser history (which I want) without keeping search history before.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I edited my comment in a hurry, before the 5 minute window expired. I meant to say that _search_ and form history are linked. Browsing history is independent.

Comment: @AFH Well, I have the search history unchecked and still the history shows up. Also, I did uncheck browser history and that actually seemed to prevent search history from beeing saved. I'm rather confused now.

Comment: I have to admit, so am I! As an aside, I recently switched from Firefox to [Pale Moon](http://www.palemoon.org/), having got increasingly fed up with the number of things that stopped working in Firefox: the loss of Java was the tipping point. Pale Moon supports most of the add-ons that I have come to rely on in Firefox, albeit in earlier versions, and I have now standardised on this. I would have adopted Chrome, but some crucial extensions have no equivalent.

Comment: Pause history. Google how

Comment: @DaniSpringer Tried that as well. Still showing up.

Comment: So if you pause and then search for, say, pizza, then pizza is still suggested? Try a different browser. Does it still happen?